# How to overcome spark java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space and java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded issues?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, hive, spark-streaming

Im trying to join operation , here table1 is having 3 gb of data and table 2 is having 120 gb of data. To avoid shuffle im broadcasting table 1.

While executing im getting these errors:
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded

Spark Configs im using:

```
--executor-memory 18g
--conf spark.sql.autoBroadcastJoinThreshold=3221225472
--conf spark.driver.maxResultSize=0 --executor-cores 4
--conf spark.reducer.maxReqsInFlight=1
--conf spark.shuffle.useOldFetchProtocol=true
--conf spark.shuffle.io.retryWait=60s
--conf spark.shuffle.io.maxRetries=10
--conf spark.network.timeout=800
--conf spark.driver.memory=16g
--conf spark.executor.memoryOverhead=2g
--conf spark.reducer.maxSizeInFlight=128m
--conf spark.maxRemoteBlockSizeFetchToMem=256m
--conf spark.dynamicAllocation.maxExecutors=600
--conf "spark.executor.extraJavaOptions=-XX:MaxDirectMemorySize=2048m"
--conf spark.sql.shuffle.partitions=6000
--conf spark.shuffle.compress=true
--conf spark.io.compression.codec=zstd
--conf spark.io.compression.zstd.level=2
```

I tried to increase the executor memory,driver memory and partitions but still im facing the same issue.

Comment: You can try this al `df_final = df1.join(df2).persist(StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK)`  

https://stackoverflow.com/a/62504059/3238085   Increase your disk storage if you cannot increase memory. It maybe possible that your joined result could be very large.

Comment: So, you mean to say once join happens in the executor each executor will send result back to driver?